# Python Regex - how to find string between html tags?

Tags: python, html, regex

I am trying to extract the string between Html tags below:

```
<div class="td-wrap">
   <a href="/universities/university-cambridge" class="uni-link">University of Cambridge </a>
</div>
```

I want to have a regular expression that leaves me with:

```
University of Cambridge
```

How can I get the target text without using Beautifulsoup?

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: One way would be to [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) on the tags so you'll need to come up with a regular expression to match the start and end tags. Have a go then post back here if you have problems. You're expected to make an honest attempt at solving your problems first before asking here.

Comment: I feel a strong need to link to this classic answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4177009

Answer (score 0):

Html is tricky and BS4 is the recommended way

Anyway, you could try somme Regex stuff

```
import re

s = """<div class="td-wrap"><a href="/universities/university-cambridge" class="uni-link">University of Cambridge </a></div>"""

## ANSWER CORE ##
match = re.search(r"<(\w)+.[^>]*>([^<]+)</\1", s)

print(match.group(2))
```

Output:

```
University of Cambridge
```

In at the end of the regex, "\1" is a back reference to the first subgroup "(\w)".
the match.group(2) returns the 2nd matching group extracted by "([^<]+)".